# Getting Ubuntu Minimal + LXDE to automount USB drives

Tags: usb-drive, automount, desktop-environments, lxde

I am trying to get Ubuntu Minimal +_ LXDE to auto mount my USB drives. Currently I need to do

```
pmount /dev/sdb1
```

manually. Also I have LXDE > Preferences > Automount all checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get it working with the pretty gui tools, maybe looking at the automount documentation and tweaking your /etc/auto.master: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Automount-4.html